# continuity proof using heine's definition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ be such that $ |f(x)| \leq |x| $

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$

I am trying to use Heine's definition but not sure how to apply it when f(x) is not defined explicitly

Comment: That's not a definition for $f$, but it doesn't matter. Heine's definition of continuity at $p$ is that any sequence $x_n \to p$ should have $f(x_n) \to p$, right? In that case, you don't need to have $f$ defined explicitly; just show that $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ implies that any such sequence $x_n \to 0$ has $|f(x_n)| \to 0$ and thus $f(x_n) \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. 
\begin{align*}
\left| f(x) - f(0) \right| \leq |f(x)| + |f(0)| \leq |x| + |0| = |x|
\end{align*}
Choose $\delta < \varepsilon$. Now
$$
|x| < \delta \implies 0 < |f(x)| \leq |x| < \varepsilon
$$
which means that $f$ is continuous at $0$.